How to resolve SpotBugs warning about exposing internal representation with Android Data Binding?
I'm working on an Android project using data binding, and I've encountered a warning in the SpotBugs violation report that I'm not sure how to address. Here's the setup:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>

package com.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.example.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Inflate the layout using the generated binding class
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        // Set the root view as the content view of the activity
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    }
}

Issue:
I am getting the following warning from SpotBugs:
com.example.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.getRoot() may expose internal representation by returning ActivityMainBinding.rootView
Questions:
Is this warning something I need to worry about in the context of using data binding in Android?
Is my usage of getRoot() to set the content view correct and safe?
How can I resolve or suppress this SpotBugs warning if it’s not an actual issue?
Are there any best practices I should follow to avoid such warnings?
What I’ve Tried:
Ensured that the layout file is properly set up for data binding.
Used ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater()) to inflate the layout and set the content view.
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

to remove the above warning from spotbugs report. add the below code in your spotbugs-exclude-filter.xml
 <Match>
    <Source name="~.*/databinding/.*"/>
  </Match>

